# How do you use jQuery's .draggable to drag a table cell?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, draggable, user-experience

In this Fiddle I want to make a jQuery or Javascript interaction that will allow me to drag the first table cell (Name) and pull it out. .draggable seems to only work with divs. Is there a solution or should i give up on trying to make a UI using tables?
http://jsfiddle.net/4XyzJ/33/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out with this plugin http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/

and with table cells is this is what you need http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/dd/dnd3.php

Comment: I will add this idea to a fork of http://jsfiddle.net/4XyzJ/33/ I give this the answer even though I have not tested it yet, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a div in the cell and drag that.

Comment: I tried this actually, it did not seem to work. I can reference the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4XyzJ/33/

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/4XyzJ/44/  I corrected your selector and clicked the jQueryUI checkbox.